# Clickhouse-mysql does not run

Tags: clickhouse

I have install all the requirements, when I try to run the clickhouse-mysql I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/clickhouse-mysql", line 7, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .main import Main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql.config import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql.reader.mysqlreader import MySQLReader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/reader/mysqlreader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .binlogstream import BinLogStreamReader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/binlogstream.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pymysql.util import int2byte
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql.util'
```

I have the required module installed but it seems there is an issue with it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to this commit https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/commit/744da2f5b853702c27be0ab10dad3312bed11030 Try to install PyMySQL==0.10.1

Comment: Solved the issue...much appreciate your help.

Comment: I have posted a new question regarding issue with clickhouse, this is the link, would really appreciate any help   :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280294/import-data-from-mysql-to-clickhouse-fails