# Import data from mySQL to Clickhouse fails

Tags: clickhouse

I have configure mysql and clickhouse so that I can import mysql data into clickhouse, when I run the following command clickhouse-mysql-data reader connects and creates a table inside clikhouse server but fails on insert queries. Following is the output:

```
2021-04-27 14:05:42,730/1619514342.730035:INFO:Starting
2021-04-27 14:05:42,730/1619514342.730357:DEBUG:{'app': {'binlog_position_file': None,
         'config_file': '/etc/clickhouse-mysql/clickhouse-mysql.conf',
         'create_table_json_template': False,
         'create_table_sql': False,
         'create_table_sql_template': False,
         'csvpool': False,
         'daemon': False,
         'dry': False,
         'install': False,
         'log_file': None,
         'log_level': 0,
         'mempool': False,
         'mempool_max_events_num': 100000,
         'mempool_max_flush_interval': 60,
         'mempool_max_rows_num': 100000,
         'migrate_table': True,
         'pid_file': '/tmp/reader.pid',
         'pump_data': False,
         'with_create_database': False},
 'converter': {'clickhouse': {'column_skip': [],
                              'converter_class': None,
                              'converter_file': None},
               'csv': {'column_default_value': None, 'column_skip': []}},
 'reader': {'file': {'csv_file_path': None, 'nice_pause': 1},
            'mysql': {'blocking': True,
                      'connection_settings': {'host': '222.133.111.62',
                                              'password': 'pass',
                                              'port': 3306,
                                              'user': 'chreader'},
                      'log_file': None,
                      'log_pos': None,
                      'nice_pause': 1,
                      'resume_stream': False,
                      'schemas': None,
                      'server_id': 1,
                      'tables': ['vtc.incoming_calls'],
                      'tables_prefixes': None}},
 'table_builder': {'clickhouse': {'connection_settings': {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                                                          'password': '',
                                                          'port': 9000,
                                                          'user': 'default'},
                                  'dst_cluster': None,
                                  'dst_create_table': True,
                                  'dst_distribute': False,
                                  'dst_schema': None,
                                  'dst_table': None,
                                  'dst_table_prefix': None},
                   'mysql': {'column_skip': [],
                             'host': '222.133.111.62',
                             'password': 'pass',
                             'port': 3306,
                             'schemas': None,
                             'tables': ['vtc.incoming_calls'],
                             'tables_prefixes': None,
                             'user': 'chreader'}},
 'table_migrator': {'clickhouse': {'connection_settings': {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                                                           'password': '',
                                                           'port': 9000,
                                                           'user': 'default'},
                                   'dst_cluster': None,
                                   'dst_create_table': True,
                                   'dst_distribute': False,
                                   'dst_schema': None,
                                   'dst_table': None,
                                   'dst_table_prefix': None},
                    'mysql': {'column_skip': [],
                              'host': '222.133.111.62',
                              'password': 'pass',
                              'port': 3306,
                              'schemas': None,
                              'tables': ['vtc.incoming_calls'],
                              'tables_prefixes': None,
                              'tables_where_clauses': None,
                              'user': 'chreader'}},
 'writer': {'clickhouse': {'connection_settings': {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                                                   'password': '',
                                                   'port': 9000,
                                                   'user': 'default'},
                           'dst_distribute': False,
                           'dst_schema': None,
                           'dst_table': None,
                           'dst_table_prefix': None},
            'file': {'csv_file_path': None,
                     'csv_file_path_prefix': '/tmp/csvpool_',
                     'csv_file_path_suffix_parts': [],
                     'csv_keep_file': False,
                     'dst_distribute': False,
                     'dst_schema': None,
                     'dst_table': None,
                     'dst_table_prefix': None}}}
2021-04-27 14:05:42,734/1619514342.734610:INFO:sys.path
2021-04-27 14:05:42,734/1619514342.734863:INFO:['/home/adminuser/clickhouse-mysql-data-reader/clickhouse_mysql/converter',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/adminuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/haditeluser/clickhouse-mysql-data-reader',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735051:DEBUG:CHWriteConverter __init__()
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735171:DEBUG:Converter __init__()
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735296:DEBUG:[]
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735435:INFO:CHWriter() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''} dst_schema=None dst_table=None dst_distribute=False
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735559:INFO:CHClient() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''}
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735764:INFO:CHClient() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''}
2021-04-27 14:05:42,735/1619514342.735966:DEBUG:{'vtc': {'incoming_calls'}} group tables for explicitly specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,736/1619514342.736097:DEBUG:{} group tables for prefix specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,736/1619514342.736213:INFO:List for migration:
2021-04-27 14:05:42,736/1619514342.736338:INFO:  vtc.incoming_calls
2021-04-27 14:05:42,736/1619514342.736473:DEBUG:{'vtc': {'incoming_calls'}} group tables for explicitly specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,736/1619514342.736598:DEBUG:{} group tables for prefix specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,764/1619514342.764922:DEBUG:Connect to the database host=222.133.111.62 port=3306 user=chreader password=pass db=vtc
2021-04-27 14:05:42,768/1619514342.768492:INFO:Start migration vtc.incoming_calls
Running with chclient CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `vtc`;
2021-04-27 14:05:42,768/1619514342.768675:DEBUG:Connecting. Database: default. User: default
2021-04-27 14:05:42,768/1619514342.768799:DEBUG:Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000
2021-04-27 14:05:42,773/1619514342.773789:DEBUG:Connected to ClickHouse server version 21.3.4, revision: 54447
2021-04-27 14:05:42,896/1619514342.896687:DEBUG:Query: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `vtc`
2021-04-27 14:05:42,897/1619514342.897576:DEBUG:Block "" send time: 0.000080
Running with chclient CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vtc`.`incoming_calls`  (
    `id` Int32,
    `client_id` String,
    `date` Date,
    `time` Nullable(String),
    `cids` Nullable(String),
    `datetime` DateTime,
    `did_num` Nullable(String),
    `line_status` Nullable(Int32),
    `duration` Nullable(Int32),
    `billing_minutes` Nullable(Float32),
    `Last_App` Nullable(String),
    `Last_App_ID` Nullable(Int32),
    `Last_App_Data` String,
    `call-status` Nullable(String),
    `dtmf` Int32,
    `Caller_ID` Nullable(Int32),
    `Recd_File_Path` String,
    `agent_name` Nullable(String),
    `agent_no` Nullable(String),
    `Lead_Check` Nullable(Int32)
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date) ORDER BY (id,client_id,date,datetime,Last_App_Data,Recd_File_Path)
;
2021-04-27 14:05:42,899/1619514342.899724:DEBUG:Query: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vtc`.`incoming_calls`  (
    `id` Int32,
    `client_id` String,
    `date` Date,
    `time` Nullable(String),
    `cids` Nullable(String),
    `datetime` DateTime,
    `did_num` Nullable(String),
    `line_status` Nullable(Int32),
    `duration` Nullable(Int32),
    `billing_minutes` Nullable(Float32),
    `Last_App` Nullable(String),
    `Last_App_ID` Nullable(Int32),
    `Last_App_Data` String,
    `call-status` Nullable(String),
    `dtmf` Int32,
    `Caller_ID` Nullable(Int32),
    `Recd_File_Path` String,
    `agent_name` Nullable(String),
    `agent_no` Nullable(String),
    `Lead_Check` Nullable(Int32)
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date) ORDER BY (id,client_id,date,datetime,Last_App_Data,Recd_File_Path)

2021-04-27 14:05:42,900/1619514342.900012:DEBUG:Block "" send time: 0.000071
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932191:DEBUG:CHWriteConverter __init__()
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932370:DEBUG:Converter __init__()
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932487:DEBUG:[]
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932637:INFO:CHWriter() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''} dst_schema=None dst_table=None dst_distribute=False
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932763:INFO:CHClient() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''}
2021-04-27 14:05:42,932/1619514342.932946:INFO:CHClient() connection_settings={'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9000, 'user': 'default', 'password': ''}
2021-04-27 14:05:42,934/1619514342.934955:DEBUG:{'vpbx': {'incoming_calls'}} group tables for explicitly specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,935/1619514342.935480:DEBUG:{} group tables for prefix specified db/tables
2021-04-27 14:05:42,935/1619514342.935601:INFO:List for migration:
2021-04-27 14:05:42,935/1619514342.935717:INFO:  vtc.incoming_calls
2021-04-27 14:05:42,935/1619514342.935832:INFO:Start migration vtc.incoming_calls
2021-04-27 14:05:42,959/1619514342.959363:DEBUG:Connect to the database host=222.133.111.62 port=3306 user=chreader password=pass db=vtc
2021-04-27 14:05:42,962/1619514342.962478:INFO:migrate_table. sql=SELECT `id`,`client_id`,`date`,`time`,`cids`,`datetime`,`did_num`,`line_status`,`duration`,`billing_minutes`,`Last_App`,`Last_App_ID`,`Last_App_Data`,`call-status`,`dtmf`,`Caller_ID`,`Recd_File_Path`,`agent_name`,`agent_no`,`Lead_Check` FROM `vpbx`.`incoming_calls`
2021-04-27 14:05:42,986/1619514342.986669:DEBUG:Connect to the database host=222.133.111.62 port=3306 user=chreader password=pass db=vtc
2021-04-27 14:05:44,527/1619514344.527455:DEBUG:class:<class 'clickhouse_mysql.writer.chwriter.CHWriter'> insert 1 event(s)
2021-04-27 14:05:44,891/1619514344.891846:DEBUG:class:<class 'clickhouse_mysql.writer.chwriter.CHWriter'> insert 100000 row(s)
2021-04-27 14:05:44,892/1619514344.892111:DEBUG:schema=vtc table=incoming_calls self.dst_schema=None self.dst_table=None
2021-04-27 14:05:44,892/1619514344.892497:DEBUG:Connecting. Database: default. User: default
2021-04-27 14:05:44,892/1619514344.892591:DEBUG:Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000
2021-04-27 14:05:44,894/1619514344.894158:DEBUG:Connected to ClickHouse server version 21.3.4, revision: 54447
2021-04-27 14:05:44,894/1619514344.894521:DEBUG:Query: INSERT INTO `vtc`.`incoming_calls` (`id`, `client_id`, `date`, `time`, `cids`, `datetime`, `did_num`, `line_status`, `duration`, `billing_minutes`, `Last_App`, `Last_App_ID`, `Last_App_Data`, `call-status`, `dtmf`, `Caller_ID`, `Recd_File_Path`, `agent_name`, `agent_no`, `Lead_Check`) VALUES
2021-04-27 14:05:44,894/1619514344.894732:DEBUG:Block "" send time: 0.000056
2021-04-27 14:05:45,200/1619514345.200698:CRITICAL:QUERY FAILED
2021-04-27 14:05:45,200/1619514345.200894:CRITICAL:ex='NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
2021-04-27 14:05:45,200/1619514345.200971:CRITICAL:sql=INSERT INTO `vtc`.`incoming_calls` (`id`, `client_id`, `date`, `time`, `cids`, `datetime`, `did_num`, `line_status`, `duration`, `billing_minutes`, `Last_App`, `Last_App_ID`, `Last_App_Data`, `call-status`, `dtmf`, `Caller_ID`, `Recd_File_Path`, `agent_name`, `agent_no`, `Lead_Check`) VALUES
```

The last 4 lines are giving some indication of what went wrong but I am not clear on how to resolve this error. Please help.

Comment: Check errors in /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log

Comment: For the first log these are the entries:
```
2021.04.05 19:44:02.582941 [ 4008 ] {} <Warning> Access(local directory): File /var/lib/clickhouse/access/users.list doesn't exist
2021.04.05 19:44:02.582966 [ 4008 ] {} <Warning> Access(local directory): Recovering lists in directory /var/lib/clickhouse/access/
```

Comment: The second log file is a bit large so can paste it here...please advise what to do.

Comment: you can share using for exampl https://pastebin.com/